# Vscode won't lint Solidity

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity

I am having issues with vscode and Solidity. Yesterday it all worked fine and today its all broken for some reason. I have tried everything possible and the issue persists. I am using the solidity extension by Juan Blanco.

My vscode stopped highlighting errors in the code. So, for example, I have the below code:

```
function deposit(address asset, uint256 _amount) external whenNotPaused nonReentrant {
    require(_amount > 0, "Amount should be greater than 0");

    DataTypes.ReserveData storage reserve = reservesData[asset];
    DataTypes.ReserveCache memory reserveCache = reserve.cache();

    // Updates the state of the reserve
    reserve.updateState(reserveCache);

    // Updates the interest rate of the reserve
    reserve.updateInterestRates(reserveCache, asset, amount, 0);

    Why is vscode not marking this line as an error????
    var variable = boo;

    etc...
}
```

I should see errors for the lines:
**Why is vscode not marking this line as an error????
var variable = boo;**

As well as an error flagging that I passed **"amount"** to the **updateInterestRates** function instead of **"_amount"** and I see nothing.

In the Output tab of vscode for "Solidity Language Server" I get the following outputs:

Error - 18:39:57] Notification handler 'workspace/didChangeConfiguration' failed with message: Unexpected end of JSON input

Error - 18:55:21] Request textDocument/hover failed.
Message: Request textDocument/hover failed with message: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace')
Code: -32603

[Error - 18:55:31] Request textDocument/hover failed.
Message: Request textDocument/hover failed with message: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace')
Code: -32603

etc.

My settings.json has:

```
     // Solhint linting validation rules
      "solidity.solhintRules": null,
    
        // Enables / disables the solidity formatter prettier (default) or forge (note it needs to be installed)
      "solidity.formatter": "prettier",
    
      // Enables linting using either solium (ethlint) or solhint. Possible options 'solhint' and 'solium', the default is solhint
      "solidity.linter": "solhint",
    "[solidity]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "JuanBlanco.solidity",
    "editor.tabSize": 4
  },

    "solidity.solhintRules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "error",
    "no-undef": "error"
  }
```

I have even deleted vscode from my machine along with the cache and reinstalled everything, but it simply wont work.

Can someone please help?